# Gromov width of weighted projective planes

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

I am interested in knowing the Gromov width of (the complement of the three orbifold points of) weighted projective planes $\Bbb{CP}(a,b,c)$. Let me emphasize that I am mainly interested in **upper bounds** of the Gromov width, see point 2. below.

Let me be more precise:

Let $\Bbb{CP}(a,b,c)$ be the quotient of $\Bbb{C}^3 - \{0\}$ by the action of $\Bbb{C}^*$ given by $t.(z_0,z_1,z_2) = (t^a z_0,t^b z_1,t^c z_2)$ for a fixed triple of positive integers $(a,b,c)$. This space is a symplectic orbifold naturally equipped with a symplectic form coming from symplectic reduction, see e.g. VanHoof's thesis for details (https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/etd/1868/). Excluding the (up to three) orbifold points, we obtain a (non-compact) symplectic manifold, which I will call $(X,\omega_X)$. I am interested in its Gromov width, i.e. the quantity

$$ \sup \{ a \in \Bbb{R} \; \vert \; (B^4(a), \omega_0) \hookrightarrow (X,\omega_X)  \}. $$

By $(B^4(a), \omega_0) \hookrightarrow (X,\omega_X)$, I mean a symplectic embedding.

Any hints on whether this has been done somewhere or how to approach the problem are much appreciated.

Some thoughts:

1. We have to remove the orbifold points, otherwise this question makes no sense a priori.
2. Using the orbifold toric structure by Lerman--Tolman and ball embedding techniques by Schlenk/Traynor, it is not hard to construct ball embeddings and these candidates look optimal to me. This suggests that the answer should be the minimal integral affine distance of a vertex to an opposite edge in the orbifold Delzant polytope. (Sorry, I don't have an explicit formula in terms of $a,b,c$...)
3. Maybe one can use the literature on Gromov-Witten invariants in weighted projective spaces in order to approach the question. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with it and hints on whether this is promising would be very useful to me.

Comment: You don't exactly get a symplectic manifold. After deleting the 3 points the quotient is a smooth manifold but there are copies of $\mathbb{C}^*$  where the reduced orbifold symplectic form is singular with isotropy order $|b-a|,|c-a|,|b-c|$. I think one way people get around this (in a different context) is by considering branched covering. Or just working in the orbifold setting.